# wordpress set cookie once form is submitted

Tags: wordpress, function, cookies

I added an action into functions.php which adds cookies :

```
add_action( 'init', 'offers_cookies' );

function offers_cookies() {
    setcookie("offers_access", 'true', time()+2592000);
}
```

The cookie is added once the page is loaded.

I want to add the cookie when a user submit a form. How to do it ?

There is only one 'mail' field and the form is located into a page template

Something like this :

```
<form method="post">
    <input type="mail" name="email" placeholder="address">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Thank you

Comment: What kind of form? Where will be the form located at?

Comment: I have edited my post

Answer (score 0):

You can create a condition that will add the cookie if the post data was submitted:

```
if ( isset($_POST['email']) ) add_action( 'init', 'offers_cookies' );

function offers_cookies() {
    setcookie("offers_access", 'true', time()+2592000);
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to call a function which adds cookie ?

Comment: @Seabon `setcookie` will add if no existing cookie is found or update if existing cookie is found.

Comment: @Seabon Do you mean a function to add cookies without refreshing the page? You can do that with [javascript](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp) on the form's [submit event](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_submit.asp).